# Laravel 5.2 email unique jquery validate

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a bootstrap modal but here server side validation does not show so i tried to validate in JQuery validate plugin and  I'm trying to check for the email  if it unique in JQuery validate  but it still gives me the error message  and won't submit

Controller:

```
 public function register(Request $request){   
 $validation =$this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,'
            'password' =>'Required|AlphaNum|Between:6,8|Confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' =>'Required|AlphaNum|Between:6,8'

        ]);

      $users = new User([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($request['password']),
        ]); 
      $users->save(); 


         return redirect()->route('product.index')
                        ->with('success', 'welcome');
        }

//
        public function validateEmail(Request $request)
 {

          $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
         ]);

         if($validator->fails()){
        return Response::json(array(
            'fail' => true,
            'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
        ));
         }else {

        return Response::json(array(
          'success' => true,
          'email' => $request->input('email')
        ));
 }

 }
```

JavaScript:

```
           $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
    $(".register").submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault(); 



var form=$('.registerform');



        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: $form.attr('action'),
        data:form.serialize(),

            dataType: 'json',
success: function(result) {
    if (response.status == "OK") {
      console.log ('success');//Success!
      $('#register').modal('hide');
      $('.register').attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
      console.log ('failure');//Fail!
      $(".errors").html(result.errors);
      $('.register').attr("disabled", false);
    }
  }



        });


    });
     $.validator.addMethod("remote", 
        function(value, element) {
            var result = false;
            $.ajax({
                type:"get",
                url: "/email", // script to validate in server side
                 data:form.serialize(),

            });

            // return true if username is exist in database
            return result; 
        }, 
        "This email is already taken! Try another."
    );


 $.validator.addMethod("PASSWORD",function(value,element){
                return this.optional(element) || /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8}$/i.test(value);
            },"Passwords are 6,8 characters with uppercase letters, lowercase letters and at least one number.");

    $(".register").click(function () {

        form = $(".registerform");

        $('.registerform').validate({
             wrapper: "li",

        rules:{
        name:{
            required:true,
        },
        password:{
            required:true,
              PASSWORD : true
        },
       // password_confirmation: {required: true},

        email:{
           required:true,
            email:true,
           remote:true



        }
    },
    messages:{
        name:{
            required:"Please provide your Login",
        },
        password:{
            required:"Please provide your password",

        },
       email:{
            required:"Please provide your email adress",
            email:"it should be an email",
            //remote:  "This email is already taken! Try another."


        },
        ///password_confirmation:{
            required:"Please provide your password",
           // equalTo:"it should be equal to password"
   // }


    }
      });

      });
```